# Table attribute data type

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a help to choose data type in SQL table.
The attribute needs to take 4 options for example, I want to create table with attribute `status` but I don't know what data type it must be, and how to implement the 4 options of choose.

```
CREATE TABLE status (
   USERNAME type_of_data (options: offline, online, away, busy)
);
```

I can't create 4 more table for each option.
It is possible to do? if not, what will be the better way?

Thx

Comment: I don't know what you mean by attribute. In the code you posted, you are creating a database table named `status` that contains one column named `USERNAME` and the value must be one of "offline", "online", "away" and "busy". So are you asking what is an appropriate data type for column `USERNAME` that will force it to accept only one of the four available options?

Comment: That's right what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE status 
( 
   USERNAME     varchar(100) not null, 
   type_of_data varchar(20) not null, 
   constraint check_type check (type_of_data in ('offline', 'online', 'away', 'busy'))
);
```

The above creates a table with two columns. One is named `username` that has no restrictions (other than being mandatory) and the other is named `type_of_data`.

The values you can put into the column `type_of_data` are limited to `'offline'`, `'online'`, `'away'` and `'busy'`;

You should also find a primary key for that table. Maybe it's `username` or maybe you need to add an `identity` column to it to generate a primary key.

Comment: Thx, I think it's what I need, using constraint check

Answer (score 1):

you can define a table for Status which has 2 columns (ID(int), Status(VARCHAR(100)) fill your table Rows with (offline, online, away, busy) so you can use Their ID as a foreign Key in other tables.

it would be :

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_STATUS](
     [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [STATUS] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_STATUS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
    [ID] ASC
   )
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_USER](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[USER_ID] [int] NULL,
[USERNAME] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[STATUS_ID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_USER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_USER]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT   [FK_TBL_USER_TBL_STATUS] FOREIGN KEY([STATUS_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TBL_STATUS] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_USER] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TBL_USER_TBL_STATUS]
GO
```

Comment: How exactly to do that? I was looking to find something about status, but didn't find nothing, the first example given by @a_horse_with_no_name, is also good, but I have to do it without using check, so I think your example is close to my needs. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `VARCHAR` or `VARCHAR2` datatype in `oracle` to store the status column.

According to [DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822)

> The VARCHAR2 datatype stores variable-length character strings. When
>   you create a table with a VARCHAR2 column, you specify a maximum
>   string length (in bytes or characters) between 1 and 4000 bytes for
>   the VARCHAR2 column